# scope of javascript variables within functions within function

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the following code? Why don't the inner functions access the "inside" variable within the same parent function - yet they seem to share the same variable with peer functions?  I know that I could use "this" from within the child functions to access the "inside" variable in the parent function, but I'm puzzled as to why this is needed....  Have I effectively been creating class instances when I probably want something more static? I've been using this pattern to wrap javascript functionality, but now I'm wondering if there is a better/easier pattern that avoids this challenge of variable encapsulation (something more static)? Thank you for your insights.

```js
var wrap = function() {
  var inside = null;

  function showInside() {
    console.log(inside);
  }

  function changeInside() {
    console.log(inside);
    inside += 'test';
  }

  return {
    inside: inside,
    showInside: showInside,
    changeInside: changeInside
  };
}();

wrap.changeInside();
wrap.showInside();
wrap.changeInside();
wrap.showInside();
console.log(wrap.inside);
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with functions at all. Here is a simplified version of what you are seeing: `var foo = 42; var obj = {foo: foo}; foo = 21; console.log(obj.foo);`. JavaScript is **pass by value**. `{foo: foo}` assigns a *copy* of the value of `foo` to the property `foo`.

Comment: I think speaking of **pass by value** in JavaScript is confusing because you can also pass references as value. If `foo` was an object, you would not assign a copy of the object but a copy of the reference to the object.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak: Anything is confusing if one doesn't know about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy is a good read.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak No, JS is always pass-by-value. That you can pass reference *values* (objects) is just a part of that.

Comment: I know how passing of values and references in JavaScript works and I know pass-by-reference comes from languages that pass pointers. My point is that we shouldn't even mention this concept to learners. We rather should tell them that there are primitive types and objects in JS. When passing objects, you can change their attributes. I think this explanation is much more straightforward than mentioning a concept that requires you to know low-level tech. @Bergi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why don't the inner functions access the "inside" variable within the same parent function - yet they seem to share the same variable with peer functions?

They do.

You are confused because when you say:

```
  return {
    inside:inside,
```

You copy the **value** of the variable `inside` to the property `inside` on the new object. You do this at the time you create the object.

When you change the value of the *variable* later, it has no association with the *property*, so the *property* doesn't get updated.

---

You would need to use getter/setters to link the property to the variable.

```js
var wrap = function() {
  var inside = null;

  function showInside() {
    console.log(inside);
  };

  function changeInside() {
    console.log(inside);
    inside += 'test';
  }

  return {
    get inside() {
      return inside;
    },
    set inside(value) {
      inside = value;
    },
    showInside: showInside,
    changeInside: changeInside
  };

}();

wrap.changeInside();
wrap.showInside();
wrap.changeInside();
wrap.showInside();
console.log(wrap.inside);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help in clearing my confusion! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conceptual problem. Let see:

```
var wrap = function(){
    ...
}();
```

That last `()` there means that you aren't assigning the function to `wrap`, you're *calling the function* and assigning *its return value* to `wrap`.

The return value is

```
return {
    inside:inside,  //The value of inside (null) 
    showInside:showInside, //The local function showInside
    changeInside:changeInside //The local function changeInside
};
```

See, you haven't the variable `inside` in `wrap.inside`, you just have the value when the function was invoked.

First, you might want to do the following:

```
var wrap = function() {
    ....      
    return this; //Return the object itself
}();
```

And then, variables and functions inside a function belong to the function's scope. Can't be accessed from outside that scope. So you might instead define *properties*.

```
var wrap = function() {      
    this.inside = 1; //property

    var insideVar = 2; //variable

    this.showInside=function() { //property (with a function assigned to it)
        console.log(insideVar);
        console.log(this.inside);   
    }; 

    this.changeInside=function() { //property
        insideVar+=2;
        this.inside+=1;
    };

    return this;
}();
```

And now:

```
console.log(wrap.inside); //-> 1
console.log(wrap.insideVar); //-> undefined
console.log(wrap.changeInside());
console.log(wrap.showInside); //-> 4 and 2
console.log(wrap.inside); //-> 2
```

Hope the difference is clear. Otherwise just ask for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help! I think you found the same problem in my code and understanding, however the accepted answer was more clear and helpful for me.  The main reason I use and like the pattern is the encapsulation and ability to selectively hide and expose functions and variables from the code I'm encapsulating inside the function. I started out using straight objects for encapsulation, but they were much messier and difficult to manage for me as there might be many needed functions and variables which were exposed yet were only useful and needed inside the object.... Thanks again.